# Do break points use methods like suspend and resume while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, thread-safety, breakpoints

This question has been puzzling me for a long time. Breakpoints are really great when debugging the code but how exactly do they work?

I understand that `suspend`, `stop` and `resume` are deprecated. Do breakpoints add infinite **while** loops at their positions to halt the process and use some other `thread` to change the **condition** when we click on resume from the **IDE**.

In case they are using the deprecated methods, how safe are they?

This brings me to the next question that while using break points, is it possible that they have messed up the threads and the behaviour of the program is different from what it would have without break points.

Comment: [JDWP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html)

Comment: It refers to to some JDWP packet based protocol and a hand shake mechanism between command packet triggered by a breakpoint and reply packet in correspondence to that. I didn't get this quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Magic happens.

Specifically, the debug agent is talking to the JVM using special low-level hooks that are not accessible to normal code.  These allow the programmer to stop threads, and much more besides that an ordinary Java program can't do.

But even if the debugger did use the deprecated methods, that is still OK.  The debugger is making the calls at the behest of the programmer who understands that suspending a thread may have consequences.  For example, the programmer understands (or should do) that setting a breakpoint in one thread may cause it to not `notify` an object within a timeout, and cause another thread to get an exception.  And so on.

The fact that the methods are deprecated doesn't mean that they don't work.  What it means is that **you** should not use them in **your** Java code.

---

JDWP is part of this, but it is the protocol by which the user's debugger talks to the debug agent.  The real magic happens between the debug agent and the rest of the JVM.  If you really want / need to understand, take a look at the OpenJDK source code.

---

> This brings me to the next question that while using break points, is it possible that they have messed up the threads and the behaviour of the program is different from what it would have without break points.

Absolutely!  In addition issues like stopped threads (see above), when you run with a debug agent active, it alters the way that the JVM JIT compiler compiles things.  This can alter the behavior of code.  Indeed, if you are looking for a bug that is due to a race condition or a memory model anomaly, it is highly likely that the debugger will alter the behavior.

Comment: Does this mean that the debugger is using the methods like `suspend` to do this magic.

Comment: I don't know.  I have not looked.  However, I'm pretty sure that `suspend` would not do what is needed to implement breakpoints.  How would the debugger know exactly *when* to call `suspend` to get it to stop (reliably) at the right point?   My point ... i.e. what I said in my answer ... is that the debug agent *could* call those deprecated methods if it needed to.

Comment: But shouldn't the race conditions be avoided in multi threaded programs, I generally put them in a `synchronized` block. I think race conditions are caused by human errors.

Comment: Well yea ... but the purpose of debugging is to find human errors.  Clearly, if you don't make mistakes related to race conditions and the memory model, then you don't need to worry about that.  But here's the thing.  Many Java programmers who don't have a deep understanding of Java concurrency don't even realize they are making mistakes.  You asked about whether the debugger alters a program's behavior ... and I answered.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to look up the source code you mentioned in order to have a better understanding.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on how using a debugger might change the way JVM JIT compiles?